# Calling a javascript function defined in KRL from outside a KRL closure

Tags: krl

I'm defining a Javascript function in my KRL global block that I want to call when the user clicks a link. Here are the relevant parts of the ruleset:

```
global {
  emit <|
    function clear_hold() {
      app = KOBJ.get_application("a421x26");
      app.raiseEvent("clear_hold");
    }

  |>;
}

rule add_link_to_clear_hold {
  select when pageview ".*"
  pre {
    clear_div = << <div id="clear_hold">
      <a href="javascript:clear_hold()">Clear Hold</a>
      </div> >>;
  }
  {
    append("body", clear_div);
  }

rule clear_the_hold {
  select when web clear_hold
  {
    replace_html("#clear_link", "<div id='clear_link'>Not on hold</div>");
  }
  always {
    clear ent:hold;
  }
}
```

When I click the link I get an error message that `clear_link` is not defined.

What do I need to do to call my javascript function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is suggested to use the following name spacing method to attach JavaScript functions to the KOBJ object to avoid clashes with other apps the user might have running.

```
KOBJ.a60x33.clear_hold = function() { 
  KOBJ.log('...wohoo! You found me!'); 
}
```

The function can then be called with

```
KOBJ.a60x33.clear_hold();
```

Answer (score 3):

The function is defined inside the KRL closure, but I was calling from outside the closure. To make it visible outside I added it to KOBJ after defining the function

```
KOBJ.clear_hold = clear_hold;
```

Then to call it from the link:

```
href="javascript:KOBJ.clear_hold()
```